# PemReader in java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, pem

I am working with PEMReader and I have this code which doesn't work.

```
protected static KeyPair doReadKeyPair(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    PemReader r = new PemReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    return (KeyPair) r.readObject();
}
```

Error:

```
This method readObject is undefined forfor the type PemReader.
```

But on many websites I saw this solution, so why it works for them and not for me?

Comment: Where does `PemReader` (or should it be `PEMReader`) come from? [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)? Which version are you using? Did you look up the API documentation?

Comment: On many webs it is PEMReader, but Eclipse always need to correct to PemReader. And yes, its is from BouncyCastle (version 148) and its my bad, in documentation is 
    readPemObject()
But it isn't works too :-(
Error - Cannot cast from PemObject to KeyPair.
How could I get keypair from PemObject?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do? The javadoc for PEMReader says it is deprecated and you should use PEMParser

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader.html

Comment: I didn't notice it's deprecated. I saw solution with pemReader on this forum, so I thought it my fault.